# Как можно сократить и усовершенствовать код Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, code-style

Не могу понять, как можно избавиться от дублирования кода. `continue` не дает вынести в метод.

```
def main():
    accounts = file_to_string_array('data.txt')
    accounts = string_array_to_array(accounts)
    updated_data = accounts
    for i, account in enumerate(accounts):

        if account[8] == 'Yes':
            continue

        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru')
        imap.login(account[1], account[4])
        link = find_link(imap, 'INBOX')
        if link == '':
            link = find_link(imap, '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')
            if link == '':
                continue

        open_link(link, sleep_duration=5)

        imap.close()
        imap.logout()

        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru')
        imap.login(account[1], account[4])
        link = find_link(imap, 'INBOX')
        if link == '':
            link = find_link(imap, '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')
            if link == '':
                continue

        open_link(link, sleep_duration=1)

        imap.close()
        imap.logout()

        updated_data[i][7] = 'Yes'
        updated_data[i][8] = 'Yes'

    update_data(updated_data)
```

Comment: `link = find_link(imap, 'INBOX') or find_link(imap, '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Код с поиском ссылки

   ```
   link = find_link(imap, 'INBOX')
   if link == '':
       link = find_link(imap, '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')
       if link == '':
           continue
   ```

   Я бы лучше заменил на функцию:

   ```
   def get_link(imap: imaplib.IMAP4_SSL, search_in1: str, search_in2: str) -> str:
       link = find_link(imap, search_in1)
       if not link:
           link = find_link(imap, search_in2)
       return link
   ```

   Аналогично через оператор `or`:

   ```
   def get_link(imap: imaplib.IMAP4_SSL, search_in1: str, search_in2: str) -> str:
       return find_link(imap, search_in1) or find_link(imap, search_in2)
   ```
2. Не хорошо два раза создавать подключение к почте и закрывать, мне кажется лучше один раз сделать, а после закрыть через `try`/`finally`. Даже если будет вызван `continue`, код в `finally` выполнится, поэтому мы будем уверены, что соединение с почтовым сервером будет правильно закрыто
3. **UPD.** уточнение пункта 2, можно через контекстный менеджер открывать, тогда и try/finally с закрытием сессии не понадобится

Итого:

```
import imaplib


def get_link(imap: imaplib.IMAP4_SSL, search_in1: str, search_in2: str) -> str:
    link = find_link(imap, search_in1)
    if not link:
        link = find_link(imap, search_in2)
    return link


def main():
    accounts = file_to_string_array('data.txt')
    accounts = string_array_to_array(accounts)
    updated_data = accounts
    for i, account in enumerate(accounts):
        if account[8] == 'Yes':
            continue

        with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru') as imap:
            imap.login(account[1], account[4])
            
            link = get_link(imap, 'INBOX', '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')
            if not link:
                continue
            open_link(link, sleep_duration=5)

            link = get_link(imap, 'INBOX', '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')
            if not link:
                continue
            open_link(link, sleep_duration=1)

        updated_data[i][7] = 'Yes'
        updated_data[i][8] = 'Yes'

    update_data(updated_data)
```

Comment: Начиная с Python 3.5, можно через `with` открывать подключение. И `logout` наверно должен быть до `close()`

Comment: в последних версиях Python  появился оператор  `:=`.  Думаю, здесь он как раз кстати...  Если использовать его в `if` - код подсократится  Хотя да, конструкция `with` здесь  тоже подойдет .

Comment: Не у всех последняя версия стоит. А на серверах, так и тем более. Лучше на более-менее глубокую обратную совместимость кода ориентироваться.

Comment: @AndyPavlov, спасибо, не вникал в код работы с почтой, т.к. считал, что у автора код правильный :)

Answer (score 2):

Вынести в функцию

```
def foo(link):
   if link == '':
      link = find_link(imap, '&BCEEPwQwBDw-')
      if link == '':
          return true
   return link
```

Делать *continue*, если результат функции -  true

```
if foo(link) == true:
   continue
```

Comment: Не `true`, а `True`. Функции лучше называть осознано. Не нужно явно проверять на `True`/`False`, достаточно проверить через `if foo(link):`. И не понятно, что значит `true` при пустой ссылке, то, что ссылка пустая?